# Add content between <nav> and <ul> in WooCommerce account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm making a custom dashboard for WC and need to add content just between the `nav` and `ul` elements in WooCommerce's menu in dashboard in the easiest way.

I've seen there's a hook called [woocommerce_before_account_navigation](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_before_account_navigation) and [woocommerce_after_account_navigation](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_after_account_navigation) but those hooks add content after or before the entire `nav` element.

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to do.

[image: a busy cat]

Someone got a solution?

Comment: What kind of content are you trying to inject there?

Comment: @cabrerahector Some php, i need to display user infos, avatar and name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since WooCommerce doesn't provide hooks to inject code exactly where you need it:

### #1 Customize the navigation section from your theme

Since [WooCommerce allows you to override most of its template files](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/), you could:

1. Copy the `navigation.php` file located at `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/`.
2. Paste this file into `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/myaccount/`.
3. Make your desired changes.
4. Profit!

Keep in mind that you'll want to keep an eye on WC's updates from time to time because there might be changes in the files you're overriding that you might want/need to port over.

Or...

### #2 Inject your custom code right where you want it using AJAX & JS

Use [WordPress' AJAX API](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) to generate the HTML output you need and inject it right between the `nav` and the `ul` tags using jQuery/vanilla JavaScript.

This way you avoid having to override WC's templates. Keep in mind though that if you do this while using a caching plugin on your site you'll need to configure it so it rebuilds its cache every ~24 hours or less or else things might break for some users ([example](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/admin-ajax-php-403-forbidden-with-cache-enabler-after-24h/#post-9548228)).

Answer (score 0):

Well....the easiest but not the best way is to:

Manually put a an empty div tag so that your code becomes something like:

```
<nav class= 'woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation'>
<div style ='blah-blah'>//that div after the nav bar ;TLDR
<div id='newDiv></div>
<ul>//etc
```

Wrap up the code to  display user infos, avatar and name in a php function (I named mine
getUsernameAndStuff()) letting `id` be the id of the user.

Like :

```
<?php 
function getUsernameAndStuff(id){
//put the code here..
}
?>
```

Then  using js:

```
<script>document.getElementById().innerHTML=<?php getUsernameAndStuff(id)?></script>
```